# Incorrect junit test method name?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, methods, junit

I have method like below:

```
   @DisplayName("testCreateExecution")
   @ParameterizedTest(name = "testCreateExecution[ testId:{index}, size:{0}, side:{1} ]")
   @MethodSource(SINGLE_EXECUTION_DATA_PROVIDER)
   public void testCreateExecution(double size, char side) throws TestRunException{
    ...
    }
```

and this test is marked by junit with exclamation mark and small red arrow instead of green one as it's usually.
When I try to run it this test case is not executed (nothing happens) but then is marked as passed.
When I rename this method eg. to testCreateExecutions everything goes ok.

I'm really surprised - What is wrong with this test method name ?
This method was named by intellij renamed option but is this the reason ? Is old method cached somewhere and cuases any conflict ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, problem was caiused by not found class with data provider which I also renamed.